# No logro recibir en el backend (php) un formdata enviado con fetch

Tags: javascript, php, fetch, formdata

Llevo un par de semanas con el siguiente problema:

Tengo un formulario de registro que envío al backend vía POST con fetch. En las herramientas de desarrollador de chrome me sale que las variables se reciben, pero al debuguear las variables globales $_POST y $_REQUEST, no aparece nada. He visto que se debería recibir de la misma forma que las demás, pero simplemente me aparece vacío el debug. Cómo puedo recibir las variables correctamente?

[image: Lo que llega a registro.php]

[image: Pantallazo del formulario de registro]

[image: Pantallazo de las variables recibidas en las herramientas de desarrollador]

## register.php

```
<?php
session_start();
require 'includes/app.php';

$db = conectarDb();

//Autentificación
$errores = [];

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
  var_dump($_POST);
  $usuarioLogin = $_POST['usuarioLogin'];
  $passwordLogin = $_POST['passwordLogin'];
  if (!$usuarioLogin) {
    $errores[] = 'El usuario es obligatorio';
  } elseif (!$passwordLogin) {
    $errores[] = 'La contraseña es obligatoria';
  }
.
.
.
```

## main.js

```
'use strict';
//constantes
const formLogin = document.getElementById("formLogin");
const formRegister = document.getElementById("formRegister");
//Funciones
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  formRegister.addEventListener("submit", registerForm);
  formLogin.addEventListener("submit", loginForm);
});
function loginForm(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  fetch(this.getAttribute('action'), {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      'Content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
    },
    body: new FormData(this),
  }).then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
  });
}
function registerForm(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  fetch(this.getAttribute('action'), {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      'Content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
    },
    body: new FormData(this)
  }).then((res) => {
    return res.text();
  }).then((text)=>{
    console.log(text);
  }).catch((error)=>{
    console.error(error);
  })
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes, por favor edita la pregunta para poner el código como texto, porque es difícil interpretarlo en imágenes.

Comment: @Triby, muchas gracias. Ya lo hago.

Comment: favor escribir codigo como texto consulta [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @RobertoPaillao listo.

Comment: por lo que muestras, tu backend no responde nada

Comment: @Christian borré lo que no era importante para hacer el código más corto. Lo que es importante es lo que escribí y muestro

Comment: @MRDev no cambió nada estimado

Comment: Porque agregas el código de `login.php` si el formulario es de registro?

Comment: Intenta no enviar encabezados, con eso debería resolverse.

Comment: @MRDev corregido, pero basicamente es el mismo problema para register y login, ya que en ambos envío un formdata vía fetch y lo recibo en el backend

Comment: @Triby, usted ha sido mi salvador. Era algo tan fácil XD muchas gracias